# Libraries "X11/Xlib.h", "X11/Xutil.h", "unistd.h" for Windows

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, xlib, unistd.h

I've done a C program that takes the RGB values (0-255) of a pixel of the screen knowing its position (x,y). It works in Linux, but when I try to compile it in Visual Studio (Windows), crashes because libraries X11/Xlib.h, X11/Xutil.h, unistd.h doesn't exist.

This is the code:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getimage(XColor c, Display* d, int* rgb, int x, int y) {
    XImage* image;
    image = XGetImage(d, RootWindow(d, DefaultScreen(d)),
        x, y, 1, 1, AllPlanes, XYPixmap);
    c.pixel = XGetPixel(image, 0, 0);
    XFree(image);
    XQueryColor(d, DefaultColormap(d, DefaultScreen(d)), &c);
    rgb[0] = c.red / 256;
    rgb[1] = c.green / 256;
    rgb[2] = c.blue / 256;
}

int main () {
    int rgb[3], x, y;
    XColor c;
    Display* d = XOpenDisplay((char*)NULL);
    getimage(c, d, rgb, x, y);
}
```

How can I implement this to run in Windows?

Comment: Those are headers, not libraries. Headers are textual source files telling the compiler what's available; they're useless unless you have an implementation of the libraries themselves. These particular headers and libraries are largely specific to Unix-like systems. There are Unix emulation layers for Windows, such as Cygwin. Or you can write code with equivalent functionality that uses the headers and libraries provided by Windows; the result is going to be *very* different. There are also cross-platform libraries that abstract the differences; wxWidgets is one example.

Comment: This is a compiler error, not a crash.

Comment: If your compiler **crashes** for missing headers, you should run it in a debugger and file a bug report with all details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! At the end, I installed cygwin. The headers work now, but I've found another problem: Display *d = XOpenDisplay((char *)NULL); is not working because the parameter of the function is not correct. In Linux, (char *)NULL is the enviroment variable of the default display, but not in windows. Do you know what to write here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've written an X11 program.  X is the consensus standard for graphical displays ***on UNIX-like systems*** other than OS X (but it is also freely available for OS X).

Windows uses a completely different graphical display API.  It is conceivable that you could find an X implementation that runs on Windows, but Microsoft certainly doesn't provide one.  Since your program is quite short, your best bet is probably to *rewrite* it using the Windows API.

As for `unistd.h` (and `time.h`), I don't see anything in your program that depends on it.  If you weren't going to rewrite the program, you could resolve that part of your problem simply by removing the offending `#include` statement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! At the end, I installed cygwin. The headers work now, but I've found another problem: Display *d = XOpenDisplay((char *)NULL); is not working because the parameter of the function is not correct. In Linux, (char *)NULL  is the enviroment variable of the default display, but not in windows. Do you know what to write here?

Comment: @Sergio, if there is no X server running on the machine -- and unless you've installed one, you can be sure there isn't -- there is no display available to connect to.  Although you have succeeded in building your program, it cannot run in your present environment.  If there were an X server running then the display name string would have form something like `":0"`, but I repeat: your best bet it to rewrite the program against the Windows API.

Comment: Yes, I will do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One small part to the answer for your question may be to search around MSDN.  The following function is described there: (link below)

```
#include <Windows.h>  
...
DWORD WINAPI GetSysColor(
  _In_ int nIndex
);
```

To use that function, you must link to User32.lib which is implemented in User32.dll

The descriptions of `GetSysColor(...)` et. al. are accessible *[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724371(v=vs.85).aspx)*.  This function is one of many that support similar functionality, but warning, the usage methods will be like a completely different language. Windows programming is rarely similar to Linux programming.

Other starting points to Windows related graphical/image programming:
*[capturing an image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183402(v=vs.85).aspx)*
*[Create your own Snipping tool](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/485883/Create-your-own-Snipping-Tool)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer! At the end, I installed cygwin. The headers work now, but I've found another problem: Display *d = XOpenDisplay((char *)NULL); is not working because the parameter of the function is not correct. In Linux, (char *)NULL is the enviroment variable of the default display, but not in windows. Do you know what to write here?